# Converting nan to NaN in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a field `[X]` in a df where it has missing values and I created a new field `[Y]` based of the field `[X]` using a sub string function.

```py
df["Y"] = df["X"].astype(str).str[:4]
```

The field `df[X]` has missing values identified as `"NaN"` and the field `df[Y]` has missing values identified as `"nan"`

Is it possible to convert the `"nan"` values on the field `df[Y]` to `"NaN"` as same as on the field `df[X]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':['abndf', np.nan, 'ss', 'somestring']})

df["Y"] = df["X"].astype(str).str[:4].mask(df['X'].isna())
print (df)
            X     Y
0       abndf  abnd
1         NaN   NaN
2          ss    ss
3  somestring  some
```